# Iterate through deeply nested array in PHP

Tags: php, json, iteration, prestashop

I have data saved in JSON format (Prestashop) - I need to get *to* that data - which is deeply nested in arrays.

Here is the function:

```
public static function getAllCustomizedDatas($id_cart, $id_lang = null, $only_in_cart = true, $id_shop = null)
{
    $datas = parent::getAllCustomizedDatas($id_cart, $id_lang, $only_in_cart, $id_shop);
    var_dump($datas);
    /*
     * Iterate over $datas, you're looking for
     * [id_product][id_product_attribute][id_address_delivery][id_customization][datas]
     * Datas will contain an array of fields broken by their type. You can then decode
     * the ones that need to be decoded and return the result:
     */


    return $datas;
}
```

if I var_dump $datas I see this (I formatted this to make it a little easier for myself to read):

```
array(1) {
    [8]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> array(2) { 
                [22]=> array(4) { 
                    ["datas"]=> array(1) { 
                        [1]=> array(1) { 
                            [0]=> array(9) { 
                                ["id_customization"]=> string(2) "22" 
                                ["id_address_delivery"]=> string(1) "0" 
                                ["id_product"]=> string(1) "8" 
                                ["id_customization_field"]=> string(1) "2" 
                                ["id_product_attribute"]=> string(1) "0" 
                                ["type"]=> string(1) "1" 
                                ["index"]=> string(1) "2" 
                                ["value"]=> string(615) "[[{"name":"item[1][line1]","customization":"asdf"},{"name":"item[1][line2]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line3]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line4]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line5]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line6]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line7]","customization":""}],[{"name":"item[2][line1]","customization":"asdf"},{"name":"item[2][line2]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line3]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line4]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line5]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line6]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line7]","customization":""}]]" 
                                ["name"]=> string(20) "Client Customization" 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                    ["quantity"]=> int(2) 
                    ["quantity_refunded"]=> int(0) 
                    ["quantity_returned"]=> int(0) 
                } 
                [23]=> array(4) { 
                    ["datas"]=> array(1) { 
                        [1]=> array(1) { 
                            [0]=> array(9) { 
                                ["id_customization"]=> string(2) "23" 
                                ["id_address_delivery"]=> string(1) "0" 
                                ["id_product"]=> string(1) "8" 
                                ["id_customization_field"]=> string(1) "2" 
                                ["id_product_attribute"]=> string(1) "0" 
                                ["type"]=> string(1) "1" 
                                ["index"]=> string(1) "2" 
                                ["value"]=> string(615) "[[{"name":"item[1][line1]","customization":"asdf"},{"name":"item[1][line2]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line3]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line4]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line5]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line6]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line7]","customization":""}],[{"name":"item[2][line1]","customization":"asdf"},{"name":"item[2][line2]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line3]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line4]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line5]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line6]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line7]","customization":""}]]" 
                                ["name"]=> string(20) "Client Customization" 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                    ["quantity"]=> int(2) 
                    ["quantity_refunded"]=> int(0) 
                    ["quantity_returned"]=> int(0) 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

What will be the easiest way to get to the ["value"] portion of the deeply nested array?

This has to be fairly dynamic because depending on the amount of items this user has - the amount of arrays will change. In this example, there are 2 there (each with 2 items in 'value'). A user could add 3 or 4 or 10 items if they wanted to. But I'm just trying to get to ['value'] and convert that JSON into HTML for the view this is getting passed to.

Bonus: Know of a way to easily iterate through the JSON data?

The JSON data looks like this:

```
[
    [{
        "name": "item[1][line1]",
        "customization": "asdf"
    }, {
        "name": "item[1][line2]",
        "customization": ""
    }, {
        "name": "item[1][line3]",
        "customization": ""
    }, {
        "name": "item[1][line4]",
        "customization": ""
    }, {
        "name": "item[1][line5]",
        "customization": ""
    }, {
        "name": "item[1][line6]",
        "customization": ""
    }, {
        "name": "item[1][line7]",
        "customization": ""
    }],
    [{
        "name": "item[2][line1]",
        "customization": "asdf"
    }, {
        "name": "item[2][line2]",
        "customization": ""
    }, {
        "name": "item[2][line3]",
        "customization": ""
    }, {
        "name": "item[2][line4]",
        "customization": ""
    }, {
        "name": "item[2][line5]",
        "customization": ""
    }, {
        "name": "item[2][line6]",
        "customization": ""
    }, {
        "name": "item[2][line7]",
        "customization": ""
    }]
]
```

Comment: What is this line returning? `$datas = json_decode($datas[datas]);` I might put a var_dump just after that to debug.

Comment: I put a var_dump there, but don't see anything. This is (I believe) because this is just passed to the view (a template file) so if there is nothing listed in the .tpl to display the var_dump it will not show.

Comment: I can't speak to your exact architecture, but in those kinds of cases, a var_dump followed with `die` often gets me what I need. Alternatively, you could use `error_log`

Comment: Updated the question to include the var_dump - I turned off the caching and the override began working as intended.

Comment: There is no `["values"]` array.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just nesting a bunch of foreach statements until I had arrived at the array I wanted to. It was ugly, but functional.

Then I did json_decode across the JSON and iterated across it.

Answer (score 0):

https://packagist.org/packages/ishworkh/multi-level-array-iterator

This might be helpful in iterating through deep nested array. And then use key or hierarchy information to filter out value needed for you.

Lets say this is your array

```
$array = [
    [
        [
            [
                [
                    "datas"             => [
                        [
                            [
                                "id_customization"       => "22",
                                "id_address_delivery"    => "0",
                                "id_product"             => "8",
                                "id_customization_field" => "2",
                                "id_product_attribute"   => "0",
                                "type"                   => "1",
                                "index"                  => "2",
                                "value"                  => '[[{"name":"item[1][line1]","customization":"asdf"},{"name":"item[1][line2]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line3]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line4]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line5]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line6]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line7]","customization":""}],[{"name":"item[2][line1]","customization":"asdf"},{"name":"item[2][line2]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line3]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line4]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line5]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line6]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line7]","customization":""}]]',
                                "name"                   => "Client Customization",
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    "quantity"          => 2,
                    "quantity_refunded" => 0,
                    "quantity_returned" => 0,
                ],
                [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                "id_customization"       => "23",
                                "id_address_delivery"    => "0",
                                "id_product"             => "8",
                                "id_customization_field" => "2",
                                "id_product_attribute"   => "0",
                                "type"                   => "1",
                                "index"                  => "2",
                                "value"                  => '[[{"name":"item[1][line1]","customization":"asdf"},{"name":"item[1][line2]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line3]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line4]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line5]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line6]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line7]","customization":""}],[{"name":"item[2][line1]","customization":"asdf"},{"name":"item[2][line2]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line3]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line4]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line5]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line6]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line7]","customization":""}]]',
                                "name"                   => "Client Customization",
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    "quantity"          => 2,
                    "quantity_refunded" => 0,
                    "quantity_returned" => 0,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

You could create a function like this, that uses multi-level-array-iterator's iterate method to go over all the nested array and 
yield out found values.

```
/**
 * @param array $nestedArray
 *
 * @return Generator
 */
function extractValuesFromArray(array $nestedArray):Generator
{
    // $key is the local index key, which in this case should be 'value' we are looking to filter for
    foreach(\ArrayIterator\ArrayIteratorFacade::iterate($nestedArray) as $key => $ArrayElement)
    {
        if ('value' === $key)
        {
            yield $ArrayElement->getValue();
        }
    }
}

var_dump(iterator_to_array(extractValuesFromArray($array)));
```

should give

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(643) "[[{"name":"item[1][line1]","customization":"asdf"},{"name":"item[1][line2]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line3]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line4]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line5]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line6]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line7]","customization":""}],[{"name":"item[2][line1]","customization":"asdf"},{"name":"item[2][line2]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line3]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line4]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line5]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line6]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line7]","customization":""}]]"
  [1]=>
  string(643) "[[{"name":"item[1][line1]","customization":"asdf"},{"name":"item[1][line2]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line3]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line4]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line5]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line6]","customization":""},{"name":"item[1][line7]","customization":""}],[{"name":"item[2][line1]","customization":"asdf"},{"name":"item[2][line2]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line3]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line4]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line5]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line6]","customization":""},{"name":"item[2][line7]","customization":""}]]"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't provide link-only answers: links may get broken and the answer becomes irrelevant. Instead, put the most important bits to your post directly.

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate your suggestion @YakovL